# PHP User Admin System

Tags: php, mysql, admin

Hi I have never done an admin setup before. I am trying to make it so when a school administrator logs in, they can only view and edit the students at their school. All students have an access level of 2, all admins have an access level of 1 in a MySQL database column titled level_access.

When the admin logs in, based on what's in their 'School' field, they should see students with matching 'School' value. I can't get the results to only display users from the school that matches the admin's. Please help. Below is what I have so far. I know the problem lies with somehow matching the Admin's 'School' to the student's 'School' but I'm not sure how to correctly identify/pull the value(s) from the MySQL database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE level_access != 1 AND School='$School'"; 
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($res);
if ((mysql_num_rows($res)) > 0){
    $pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $sql, 10, 5, "");
?>

<td><?=$row['username'];?></td>
<td><?=$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'];?></td>
<td><?=$row['email'];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply print the users you could consider using the code below:

```
if ((mysql_num_rows($res)) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo $row['username'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to only echo users who have a match in the 'School' column as the admin who is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You are already selecting by $school Query will show you the result with $school .

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE level_access != 1 AND School='$School'"; 
   $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

try "rger" suggestion